# focussing on jquery data table's row and press enter key on focused row should pass row to another data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have 2 data tables. if I press enter key on the first data table's search box it should focus the first row of the first data table and I should able to walk through each row and if press "enter" key in any row that row should be added into the second data table.
[image]

my requirement in here
i tried somthing like this for focus on first row

```
`$("#first_tables_search_box").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      t.cell(":eq(0)").focus();
    }
  }); `
```

but it only focusing on single cell

and for pressing the enter key on focused cell to pass whole row into second table

```
`$("#table_1").keyup(function(event) { if (event.keyCode == 13) {
var table1 = table1.row(this).data();
    table2.row
      .add([
        table1[0],
        table1[1],
        table1[2],
        table1[3],
      ])
      .draw();
 });`
```

but this keyup event on table won't work

Comment: What have you tried?  Seems like you're just trying to get people to do your work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please remove code from the comments and edit your question to include the code you've tried.  Also indent code 4 spaces, you don't need backtics if you do that.